# ERROR: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - prisma ORM nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I am doing a login with Prisma ORM, the code works fine, but when I make a request in the client, it gives me the
result and then I get that error.

```
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:652:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/enmanuel-tg/Documentos/Trabajo/colmadon-miniproject/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/enmanuel-tg/Documentos/Trabajo/colmadon-miniproject/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/enmanuel-tg/Documentos/Trabajo/colmadon-miniproject/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at /home/enmanuel-tg/Documentos/Trabajo/colmadon-miniproject/backend/src/controllers/user.ts:20:23
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/home/enmanuel-tg/Documentos/Trabajo/colmadon-miniproject/backend/src/controllers/user.ts:6:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

I don't know what causes this error. but it would be a good idea to resolve the problem before it causes more.

Comment: It means in the `user.ts` file. After the response is already returned. There is some piece of code which is setting a header. `setHeader` which can no longer be set.

Comment: in express, use `res.set` method to set headers and make sure your `res.set` line is at the top of the function (i.e. before the line where you define/send a response)